# FPGA Board running

Tags: fpga

I must work with an FPGA board with a Nios embedded processor, it is APEX 20K200E device  [image]

I wanted to know :

- Is this board coming with a kit? I just have the board, a download cable and a power source.
- What are the first steps to start working with it?
- How to use the board with Quartus II?

Comment: Does the board have any markings like a part number? Does it have markings of a vendor other than the FPGA company? Those are the things I usually look for (and google them) to find support documents + software.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a better picture:

[image: Excalibur NIOS FPGA Board]

From the name it's an Excalibur board which is from Altera. It came as an [Excalibur Development Kit](https://www.altera.com/content/dam/altera-www/global/en_US/pdfs/literature/ds/ds_exckit.pdf). You'd imagine the board was available separately.

It dates from 2000. Silicon is still available albeit at a dear cost. The place to look for support would be on the Altera site.

The place to begin might be on the [Excalibur Devices](https://www.altera.com/products/general/devices/arm/arm-index.html) web page.

Comment: You're probably going to have to download an old version of the design software as well.